# SharePoint 2016 user account permission

Tags: sharepoint-server, service-account

I'm doing March 2019 update on SharePoint 2016 servers this weekend. The Service account that we have (for eg spfarm) is sysadmin on the SQL Server. According to the MS doc, the account also needs to have 'db_owner' permission on all SP databases, but it does not have that. Do you think I should add the db_owner permission for spfarm account before doing the update? Thank you – Kalai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not necessary. The SYSADMIN role allows the account to perform every action within the SQL instance without granting any other explicit permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the response. One more question. Do I have to use spfarm (this has SYSYADMIN, DBCREATOR,SECURITYADMIN roles) account to run the .exe file and spadmin(this has DBCREATOR and SECURITYADMIN server roles)to run the configuration wizard?

Comment: This answer depends on how the Farm was set up. Normally the „Farm“ Account is the one which runs central Administration. This account shouldnt be used to manage the farm. But it also doesnt need sysadmin in SQL and no local admin rights. So your Farm is actually Not set up perfectly best practise. As you have a separate Admin account: give it sysadmin to SQL and perform update with that. Revert sysadmin afterwards if you want or need to.

Comment: You are right the SP isn't setup right. I see spfarm in local Administrator group. BTW, did you mean to say spfarm account should manage the farm? Also, I will add SYSADMIN permission for SPAdmin and use the same to run the exe file and config wizard. Am I right? Thank you very for ur answers. This is great help!

Comment: Your farm has a bad practice config. No service account should be used to manage a farm. In addition, no service account of any sort needs Local Admin rights (unless you're running C2WTS which most farms do not need and if you do, you should use a separate service account for that service only).

Comment: I agree with you. I'm new at this workplace and may be I'll try to fix these in near future. But for this SP update I can either use SPFarm or SPAdmin with the current permission setup. Am I right?

Comment: Use Spadmin. Farm account shouldnt do any administrative Jobs even if permissions might allow.

Comment: Thank you. Will let you all know how it goes after the update.

Comment: Update went good without any issues. Thank you for all your jelp!